# RSpec is Freezing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have rspec configured installed in my rails app. It was working fine (We are just experimenting with rspec so there's only 2 tests).

They were working fine. Now rspec is freezing when it's going to perform a test using database.

I just freezes. I don't even know were to start looking because there's no error in the output.

Is there a verbose or debugging mode for rspec or someone ever faced this?

I've tried -b but it freezes before can give an error.

Output: (Rspec is configured with --format documentation)

```
[leandro@machine:~] rspec
User
```

Than, that's it. It hangs. I has to reset manually the computer twice.

This is the user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  let(:user) { User.create({
    username: "teste",
    email: "teste@teste.com",
    name: "Teste",
    phone: "123456789",
    password: "123456",
    notes: "Teste"
    }) }
  subject { user }

  it "is invalid without a username" do
    user.username = nil
    is_expected.not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

And my spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true
  config.formatter = :documentation #:progress, :html, :textmate
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
end
```

**SOLUTION**

It turns out that `delayed_job_active_record` gem was causing the hanging.

I don't know why, but as @Greg Malcolm I looked into the `log/teste.log` and rspec was feeezing right after createing the delayed jobs database and setting up a new user.

I've restricted the gem just for development and production enviroment, and it worked!

Comment: Can you show a console output of how far you get to before it freezes so we can get a better idea of where the freeze is occuring? In particular I'd be interested to see if the rails environment is loading successfully.

Comment: That's the problem. There's no output!. I have a `describe User do` and some examples in it. I have configured rspec to output in documentation format. So it prints `User` and then hangs.

Comment: What version of rails?  Your test db might be out of date, try running `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Rails 4.1.0, Rspec 3.1.0

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare
WARNING: db:test:prepare is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details.` 
Same thing

Comment: If you Ctrl+C out after it hangs does it give you a stack trace when it finally terminates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard of a rake like verbose feature for rspec. But it's probably more useful to look through `log/test.log` and see what shows up there. It shows database activity which is part of a freeze effect.

You might also want to `rails console` into test and make sure your database connection is working right.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tried rails console and rails server and both work. I have looked at log/test.log,  and there is no output at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the `./log/test.log` file. As this file tends to grow big, use the [`tail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) command to read the last n lines.

For example, to read the last 5 lines of the log file, execute the following command:

```
tail -5 ./log/test.log
```

In my case, my Google Pub/Sub emulator was hanging.

```
[ActiveJob] Failing with status #<struct Struct::Status code=4, details="Deadline Exceeded", metadata={}>
[ActiveJob] calling pubsub.googleapis.com:443:/google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/GetTopic
```

It might also be helpful to use `tail -f ./log/test.log`, to keep track of the logs while RSpec is running. You can read more about it on ["Tail Your Test Logs"](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tail-your-test-logs), by thoughtbot.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty old question but in case anybody else will get this. I've got the same strange Rspec behaviour today because of left `--drb` option in project `.rspec` file after removing DRb server (spork or zeus). Just make sure Rspec have DRb disabled if you don't have spork or zeus installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue of Freezing rspec but in my case there were 2 possible reason.

Consider the following check to find causes and apply solutions respectively:

**Check If `rails c` is also freezing along with `rspec .`**

**1. Database Migration in Test Environment:**

- **Check:** Ensure migrations are applied for the test environment.
- **Solution:**

  ```
  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
  ```
- **Reason:** An outdated test database can cause inconsistencies leading to freezes.

**2. Spring Interference:**

- **Check:** If `rspec .` and `rails c` are freezing.
- **Solution:** To potentially resolve this freezing issue: **Reset Spring** using:

  ```
  bin/spring stop
  ```

  After stopping Spring, attempt running `rspec .` or `rails c` again.
- **Reason:** Stopping Spring resets its state, often resolving these issues. Because when you issue the command to stop Spring, you're essentially halting its processes and any cached or preloaded application state it holds. In cases where Spring has run into a **conflict or a bug**, stopping it resets this preloaded state. The next time you run a command like `rspec .`, Rails will **boot without Spring** interference, often resolving the freezing issue. If you then start Spring again, it will **preload a fresh state**, which ideally should be free of the problematic state that was causing the freeze initially.