# Rspec hangs on Ruby 2.7.4 with no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working on an upgrade from Ruby 2.6.8 to 2.7.4. Everything was painless, except that now the Rspec suite just freezes a few tests in, with no output, error, warning or anything. I've left it to continue for over an hour and it never progresses.

I've tried running `rspec --backtrace`, but that yields no more info.

Does anyone know how I may be able to debug this?

```
ruby (2.7.4)
rspec-rails (3.9.0)
rails (5.2.5)
```

Comment: _"a few tests in"_ – is it always the same test that freezes?

Comment: Always the same, yep.

Comment: So what does that test do? How is it different from the tests before? Commenting out lines or adding some simple `puts` calls between them should help to find the problem.

Comment: On Ruby 2.6.8 all of the tests just run through as you would expect. Here, it just gets about 30 tests in and then progresses no further. `puts` probably is the way to go, but even if i can track down the specific test that's failing it's going to be tough to find the _reason_ it's failing with no output to view

Comment: Run `rspec -fd` to see the spec’s names then narrow down the failing line with `puts` / comments.

Comment: Wow @Stefan thx for your help. Eventually got to the bottom of it. See answer below if interested.

Comment: Could another instance of rspec have still been running? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088355/why-wont-rspec-run-rspec-just-hangs-after-starting

Answer (score 1):

Holy cow, finally figured this one out. Apparently Rails `5.2.x` is effectively incompatible with Ruby `2.7.x`. After updating to Rails `6.0.0`, everything seems to be peachy-keen again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. In my case The solution was Addressing the **Spring gem**.

**Steps to resolve:**

1. Stop Spring:

```
bin/spring stop
```

2. Retry running RSpec.
   `rspec .`

This solution worked effectively for me. For more details, see my full explanation on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76966113/7612560). If you're facing a similar RSpec issue, it might be of help.